# AngularJS - Find the Env the application runs?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, environment-variables, env

I have an angular application. I have it set by scafolding using `Yeoman` and its `generator-angular` app. I am testing it using `grunt serve`.

I have few basic questions -

1. Is this a *node application*?
2. Since this application is going to be run in two environments (like pre-production and production), is there a way in my angular app I get the details of which environment it is run?

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to explain

1. No this is a ***framework*** developed by **Google** team
2. There are many ways and tools to do that like **gulp** , **grunt**, **webpack** and yes there are many ways to set the environment and to get the environment

Try to look at any angular-seed and tutorial with tools like gulp, grunt and webpack.